# Difference between client.on(events.NewMessage())" and "events.register(events.NewMessage())

Tags: python, telethon

What are the differences between telethon
client.on(events.NewMessage())" and "events.register(events.NewMessage())

Answer (score 0):

In Telethon v1, `client.on` immediately registers the event handler to the client. This means it is already able to dispatch updates to your handler.

`events.register` simply attaches extra information to your handler function saying "this function can handle these event types". Then, when you use `client.add_event_handler(your_function)`, it already knows it should handle `events.NewMessage`.

```py
@events.register(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    ...

client.add_event_handler(handler)

# the above is equivalent to:

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    ...
```

The first form is useful when you don't have access to the client (e.g. it's in another file).